# Is deinit called when init throws an exception?

Tags: swift

Consider the following example class:

```
class SocketWrapper {
    let sock: Int32

    init() throws {
        try sock = SocketWrapper.createSocket()
    }

    deinit {
        close(sock)
    }
}
```

What happens if createSocket() throws and the init() therefore fails? sock would be left uninitialized. Is deinit still called (on an partially uninitialized object) when init() throws?

Comment: I doubt it because if `createSocket` throws, then `sock` is never assigned. That should give you a hint, that `close(sock)` wouldn't really work.

Comment: Okay I just did a simple example. In fact it is NOT called as expected. Just did not find any normative source for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`deinit` is not called on instances that have not been correctly initialized.

If `init` fails for some reason, then the class instance never starts existing. Therefore, there is no instance on which `deinit` could be called.

If `deinit` could be called on a partially initialized instance, it would break the contract of non-optional properties - in your example the `socket` property would not get assigned and it would still be accessible in `deinit` as a non-optional but without a value.